# Grouping , sorting and sum based on XML attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have XML like below and want ouput like . 
How to write the powershell script to get desired output

```
<onds>
  <ond oc="AF" o="DXB" dc="GB"  ds="London Heathrow" dfs="london-heathrow" tp="0" />
  <ond oc="AE" o="DXB" dc="KW"  ds="Kuwait" dfs="kuwait" tp="619730" />
  <ond oc="AE" o="DXB" dc="PK"  ds="Karachi" dfs="karachi" tp="1" />
  <ond oc="AE" o="DXB" dc="IN"  ds="Mumbai" dfs="mumbai" tp="465861" />
  <ond oc="AE" o="DXB" dc="LB"  ds="Beirut" dfs="beirut" tp="366572" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GB"  ds="London Heathrow" dfs="london-heathrow" tp="0" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GB"  ds="Manchester" dfs="manchester" tp="2" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="IT"  ds="Rome" dfs="rome" tp="11978" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="FR"  ds="Paris" dfs="paris" tp="10878" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GB"  ds="London Gatwick" dfs="london-gatwick" tp="1" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="IE"  ds="Dublin" dfs="dublin" tp="8544" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="NL"  ds="Amsterdam " dfs="amsterdam" tp="839000" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GR"  ds="Athens" dfs="athens" tp="7807" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GB"  ds="Glasgow" dfs="glasgow" tp="6998" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="AE"  ds="Dubai" dfs="dubai" tp="6986" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="ES"  ds="Barcelona" dfs="barcelona" tp="6231" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="GB"  ds="Birmingham" dfs="birmingham" tp="6104" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="DE"  ds="Frankfurt" dfs="frankfurt" tp="5122" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="IT"  ds="Milan" dfs="milan" tp="4952" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="IT"  ds="Venice" dfs="venice" tp="4357" />
  <ond oc="AU" o="ADL" dc="DK"  ds="Copenhagen" dfs="copenhagen" tp="4323" /> 
</onds>
```

Output should be like Group by "dc" attribute with-in same "oc" i.e AU attribute and then sum the tp based on "dc" parameter and sort in descending in Powershell

In case of oc="AU".

1. All data should be group based on "dc" and added the tp value and then sort the whole data based on tp value
2. like we have 4 dc="GB" inside the all oc="AU" , need single record with sum of based on tp value then sorting.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a script writing service. We are here to help you with speific issues that you have with code that you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know how to convert that XML into something usable for your use case.

Here is a good post on converting XML to PSOject so you can work with it.

> Convert XML to PSObject
>
> I'm having trouble figuring out the dot notation or XPath query to
> extract the  attributes/elements and convert $b back to the original
> PSObject.
>
> [Convert XML to PSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242995/convert-xml-to-psobject)

Once you get past all the conversion, it's just using the normal grouping features built into PowerShell.

See this write up

> Use the PowerShell Group-Object Cmdlet to Display Data
>
> One of the things about learning to use Windows PowerShell is that
> Windows PowerShell can slice-and-dice data so easily. It becomes a
> quick data analysis tool that allows network administrators, analysts,
> and others to parse data to quickly discover and remediate issues. It
> can also be used to audit baseline information, or even to spelunk
> through reams of statistical data.
>
> One cmdlet that allows this analysis is the Group-Object cmdlet. In
> its most basic form, the Group-Object cmdlet accepts a property from
> objects in a pipeline, and it gathers up groups that match that
> property and displays the results. For example, to check on the status
> of services on a system, pipe the results from the Get-Service cmdlet
> to the Group-Object cmdlet and use the Status property. The command is
> shown here.
>
> Get-Service | Group-Object -Property status
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/11/use-the-powershell-group-object-cmdlet-to-display-data